# Scala zipWithIndex over a sequence of Strings, do something different with last entry

Tags: scala

I have a `Seq[String]` the represent a file, every String is a line in the file.

I'm iterating over the lines and parsing the record:

```
fileLines.zipWithIndex.foreach {
      case(fileLine, filePosition) => parseRecord(fileLine, filePosition)
}
```

Now, for the last record I need to do a different parsing. Let's say `parseLastRecord()`. What is the best Scala-way to do it?

The main reason for my question is that it would be **totally fine** to do the last line parsing **inside parseRecord that I already use**, but, I don't want to pass the filePosition+totalSize into it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pattern matching you can check the index and call whichever function you want to call from there.

eg. if last element I'm printing something otherwise each element in following example.

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).zipWithIndex.foreach{ 
    case (element, index) if index == 3 => println("last element") 
    case (element, index) => println(element)
}
```

output

```
1
2
3
last element
```

So, your case would be something as below,

```
fileLines.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case(fileLine, filePosition) if filePosition == fileLines.length-1 => parseLastRecord(fileLine, filePosition)
  case(fileLine, filePosition) => parseRecord(fileLine, filePosition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using pattern matching

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4)
val spe = l.length - 1
l.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case(item, pos) => {pos match { case `spe` => println(s"$item $pos special"); case _ => println(s"$item $pos");}}}
```

in your case

```
val last = fileLines.length - 1
fileLines.zipWithIndex.foreach {
      case(fileLine, filePosition) => {filePosition match { 
      case `last` => parseLastRecord(fileLine, filePosition)
      case _ => parseRecord(fileLine, filePosition);
}
```